# Epic AppOrchard's apps - oauth error response comes with statusCode 200

Tags: oauth, hl7-fhir

When going through Epic's App Orchard Oauth flow , any misconfiguration of the app results in an error which says "INVALID_CLIENID".

One issue is that error text is confusing because it isn't the clientId that is incorrect for some other config parameters (could be an incorrect redirect_uri for example).

Another issue is that such error response comes back with status code 200 - indicating successful request.

Is there a way to get an error code indicating a failed request ? Some code in the 4xx range

Answer (score 2):

For INVALID-CLIENT-ID, in the current version of the software you just need to check all of the different causes.

Common causes of the INVALID-CLIENT-ID error include:

- Providing an actual invalid client ID.
- Providing a redirect_uri that isn't associated with your client.
- Performing a FHIR interaction (read/search) on a resource that isn't listed in the FHIR API Scope for your client.

Comment: What about the status code 200 ? Doesn't seem right to respond with 200 when there is an issue with authentication

Comment: I think something is actually off about the https://apporchard.epic.com/interconnect-ao83prd-oauth server. I got it working at some point, but had to change the redirect_uri declared in my app. After that I am no longer able to get a successful authentication response. I know it takes 2 hours to refresh the server when any changes are made. It has been a day and still no luck. There really need to better error handling responses, so that developers could debug what is going on. I have a feeling sandbox server didn't redeploy correctly but it's hard to tell since there are no details in errors

Comment: @HIT_girl Where did you find this 2 hour server refresh documented?

Comment: @Catfish It's not documented anywhere. An Epic TS once told me when I was struggling with my app's params not getting picked up. There is a lot of Epic internal documentation which they didn't post to the dev documentation site.